# I have react app version 18 and i want install react-router dom version 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

when i install react-router dom version 5 error appers.
I assume the error is caused by my react version, what can I do to fix it?

```
$ npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.8.1" from react-select@5.4.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-select
npm ERR!       peer react-select@"^5.0.0" from react-select-async-paginate@0.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run the npm command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

```
EXAMPLE: npm install react-router-dom --force
```

Comment: Thanks, the installation works!!, but I'm encountering a new problem that when I want to switch between routers I have to do a refresh

Comment: read the react-router-dom documents carefully, and execute the code. thank you...

Comment: i used to work with react router dom , but with react v17 , and now my react version is 18 , maybe this is the problem?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select-async-paginate": "^0.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering a new problem that when I want to switch between routers I have to do a refresh

````
import "../src/assets/sass/global.scss";
import { Header } from "./components/Header";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Favorite } from "./pages/Favorite";
import { WeatherApp } from "./pages/WeatherApp";

export function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <main className="container-app">
          <Switch>
            <Route component={Favorite} path="/favorite" />
            <Route component={WeatherApp} path="/" />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Change the HashRouter to BrowserRouter